# R: Problem with highlighting a row in datatable

Tags: r, datatable, flexdashboard

I have been learning `flexdashboard` to make dashboards recently. I am trying to set a specific row to `bold` but it won't work properly if I set the `rownames` to `False`. Here is an example:

```
# This example sets the 3rd row to bold
df <- data.frame(
a = runif(3),
b = runif(3),
c = runif(3))
library(DT)
df %>%
  datatable(rownames = T,
            options = list(pageLength = 3,
                         searching = F,
                         lengthChange = F,
                         info = F,
                         paging = F,
                         ordering = F,
                         columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:3)))) %>% 
  formatStyle(
  0,
  target = "row",
  fontWeight = styleEqual(3, "bold"))
```

The above example won't work if `rownames = F`. I don't want `rownames` to be shown. What's the cause and how should I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turning off row names removes the index that you're referencing to highlight the row. So we need to create our own:

```
df$index <- seq(1,3)
```

Then, we create the `datatable`, and hide `df$index` using `list(visible = FALSE, targets = c(3))` in `columnDefs`

```
df %>%
  datatable(rownames = F,
            options = list(pageLength = 3,
                         searching = F,
                         lengthChange = F,
                         info = F,
                         paging = F,
                         columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = 0:2), list(visible=FALSE, targets = c(3))))) %>% 
  formatStyle('index',
  target = "row",
  # this says 'style rows bold where index == 3'
  fontWeight = styleEqual(3, "bold"))
```